# Unable to use port number in Facebook's "site url" setting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, settings, developer-tools

I have been creating a really small facebook app and I have just realized that the settings page in FB's dev section has changed. The options remained tho, so I went ahead and filled in the most important things (the required ones). When I got to these:

- App domain
- Site URL

Now for local testing I always fill `localhost` and that is ok. However, before, I could put the site url like this:

```
http://localhost:8872/myapp/
```

Now this doesn't work anymore, it simply refuses to take it and shows me: *Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can.* Hm.

If I change the site url to this:

```
http://localhost/myapp/
```

It is saved without problems. It makes my wonder - did Facebook change something and it will stay so, is it indeed their bug and will be fixed, or am I doing something wrong? Please note that it works alright without the port! However, I really need the port there. Thanks!

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Not good if you're doing port forwarding to test on small devices.